# PHPUnit in Laravel 5.1 flush request()?

Tags: php, laravel, request, phpunit

Looks like I don't know some basic things about PHPUnit. My problem:

In **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
   public function boot() {
      request()->country_id = 100;
   }
}
```

In **IndexController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request) {
   dd(request()->country_id);
}
```

Controller here for example, it could be used in views, controllers, everywhere...

Basic test from box **ExampleTest.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5');
    }
}
```

In browser it will display **100** , when I'm using in CLI "phpunit tests/ExampleTest" it will return **null**. Why?

And is it right to use request() this way? Because each country have own domain, and domain (host) is a part or request. So I decide to make country part of request too, it have a sense in my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It was my mistake. It should be in **RouteServiceProvider** instead of **AppServiceProvider**. Thanks to all!